# Adding a Label to Bokeh Span

Tags: python, bokeh

I want to label my Span annotations in Bokeh just as is done in the plot below. (Sorry for the link, my reputation won't allow me to post as an image)
 https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj-vOX589LMAhWh8YMKHYe0CsIQjRwIBw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmathematica.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F80467%2Fadding-annotations-to-plot-with-vertical-leader-line-to-the-curve&psig=AFQjCNE_kMOcJTDxiDbCPdZY2T2-Rk44Vw&ust=1463086437547238

Comment: Label annotations are coming in `0.12`, for now you could use `Figure.text` glyph method.

Comment: @bigreddot Would you revisit this question in the context of 0.12